# $P=x^3 + x^2 + ax + 1$, what is $a$ when $ P$ is a rational numbers, also satisfies $ 0= x^2+2x-2$

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

$x^3 + x^2 + ax + 1 $

$0= x^2+2x-2$

$x= - 1 \pm \sqrt 3$

$x^3 + x^2 + ax + 1 = x^3 + 2 - 2x + ax + 1  $
 Or $x(x^2 + x) + ax + 1 = x(2-x) + ax + 1 = 2x + 2x - 2 + ax + 1 =4x+ax-1$

If i sub $x= 1 \pm \sqrt 3$ into $4x+ax-1$
 I got wrong answer. Where am i wrong?

Comment: $x=-1\pm \sqrt 3$ would be better, I think.